# how do i read a specific line in a text file in java?

Tags: java

I have a code that needs to read lines from a 95 line text file and put each one in a string variable quickly. However, it won't be in a linear order and it will have to read each one individually. How would i do this in as efficient and compact manner possible?

Comment: As always for a question like this, you will want to tell and show us what you've tried and explain how or why it is not working well for you. We need to know just where you might be stuck.

Comment: You get that -1 for claiming to be "*very fluent*" in Java but seem  not to be capable to google a tutorial for that ..

Comment: This must be a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Quite easy:

```
final Path path = Paths.get("path/to/your/file");

final List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Then you can filter from the lines.

Starting with Java 8 you can:

```
final Path path = Paths.get("path/to/your/file");

final List<String> lines = Files.lines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
    .filter(someLambdaImplementingPredicate).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String ar = new String[95];
try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath))) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 95; i++) {
        ar[i] = br.readLine();
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that the code above does not have error handling and assumes that the file HAS 95 lines.

Comment: Since this is Java 7+, use `Files.newBufferedReader()`; also, you didn't specify the encoding

Comment: no encoding, just standard text file in ASCII

Comment: For java7, I would suggest `Files.readAllLines`.

Comment: @stealth9799 ASCII is _also_ an encoding; and since it is codepoint-wise compatible with UTF-8, well, use UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

So you are "very fluent in java", huh?

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path, charset);
```

Then do `lines.get(x)`. 95 lines is small enough to just keep all of them in memory.